# intercept-url pattern /** causing 404 error

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have searched here, google and springsource for this and could not find a solution that worked for me. I have the below spring-security.xml and when I use the pattern

`<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />`

This gives me a 404 error when it redirects to the login page. But this does not happen if I use

`<intercept-url pattern="/index*" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />`

But obviously this does not secure the rest of the app.

I'm sure this is something simple I am overlooking but the closest thing I could find was [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760011/spring-security-3-0-intercept-url-all-pages-require-authentication-but-one), Which I have already incorperated in my xml file below but still have the same issue. I have tried this without `use-expressions="true"` and I have tried switching the `intercept-url`'s around (I'm not 100% but I am fairly sure that the `/**` pattern should be the last one as I believe urls are matched in the same order as declared)

Any advice/help would be great

**spring-security.xml**

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.3.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/login" filters="none" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
        <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/welcome"
            authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
      <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="username" password="password" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
      </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

### Update

Just in case it is a factor I'm using Spring and Spring security 3.0.4.RELEASE

### Answer

Following Kris's advice I changed

```
<intercept-url pattern="/login" filters="none" access="permitAll" />
```

to:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/login" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
```

This caused a 500 Error due to the exception

```
    SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Field or property
     'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY' cannot be found on object of 
type'org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebSecurityExpressionRoot
```

I solved this by changing the `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY` to `isAnonymous()`

```
<intercept-url pattern="/login" access="isAnonymous()" />
```

Comment: `404` is not found which means the server was not able to find the appropriate handler for the request. Spring security normally throws a `403` error which is access denied. So the problem has to be with your request mapping

Comment: @ArunPJohny I had a similar situation when using permitAll, I got rid of this issue by changing to IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY. The strange thing is that instead of 403 I too got 404

Comment: Looks like a request mapping issue.

Comment: is there any log in the server

Comment: @arun-p-johny which log file should I be looking in? there are no errors in the server log when I run as above but when I make the change @kris suggested I get a 500 error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to evaluate expression 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'`

Comment: it may not be an error, normally 404 causes a warning in the logs

Comment: You get that `IllegalArgumentException` because `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY` is illegal when using expressions (`use-expressions="true"` on `http` element).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this `<intercept-url pattern="/login" filters="none" access="permitAll" />`

to

```
<intercept-url pattern="/login" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
```

Comment: I tried that but I now get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to evaluate expression 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'` caused by `SpelEvaluationException: Field or property 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebSecurityExpressionRoot'`

Comment: I changed `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY` to `isAnonymous()` and that solved it

Answer (score 9):

For completeness, here's the *real* reason this requires a change to `isAnonymous()`.

The `<http>` element has an attribute `use-expressions` which defaults to `true`.  In the default situation, you are required then to use "security expressions" instead of role names.  If you wish to use only role names in `access=` declarations, you need to turn off expressions with

```
<http use-expressions="false"> ... </http>
```

Comment: i got a similar issue and your suggestion solved the issue, thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Adds an `AnonymousAuthenticationFilter` to the stack and an `AnonymousAuthenticationProvider`. Required if you are using the `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY` attribute.
[spring secuirty](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.0.M1/reference/htmlsingle/#nsa-global-method-security)

or use `isAnonymous()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The config looks fine to me. Could it be that the `/login` page is actually not there? The second config (with `/index*`) might have only worked, because then the request you made wasn't intercepted, and consequently didn't get redericted to the non-existent `/login` page. If it was a problem with the config, Spring Security would respond with 403 not 404.

Double-check without any Spring Security configured if the `/login` url works.

Comment: no it does get intercepted when I use the `/index*` and the login page displays fine in that case, just won't work with `/**`