# All sites redirected to login page

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Dear fellow Sping'lers,

I stumbled upon a problem with the login of intercept-url's in spring.

I just want to REDIRECT ALL PAGES to my login page IF NOT logged in.

This is the security context I use. However this codes is not allowing me to access any page:

```
<security:http auto-config="true">
    <security:form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/welcome"
        authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />
    <security:logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole(ROLE_USER)" />
</security:http>
```

Thank's for your help.

Lomu

---

Changed my configuration according to [jonnieM's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15157250/intercept-url-pattern-causing-404-error):

it's now

```
<security:http auto-config="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <security:form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/welcome"
        authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />
    <security:logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
</security:http>
```

So I think "IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" did the trick :)

Cheers Lomu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should apply the `<http use-expressions="true">` setting, otherwise the values in `<intercept-url>`'s `access` attribute won't be interpreted as Spring EL expressinos.

Comment: hi zagyi,
if I'd set use-expressions="true" I need to change the config as follow's

`<security:http use-expressions="true" auto-config="true">
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="isAnonymous()" />
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
  <security:form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/welcome"
   authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />
  <security:logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
 </security:http>`

Comment: Why? What's wrong with your original config (`permitall` assigned to `/login`)? I think it should work with `use-expressions="true"`.

Comment: I checked it. "permitAll" instead of isAnonymous() is also working. You're right.