# Spring security logout - add a message only when logout triggered from a logged in user

Tags: spring, spring-security

Lets say my logout URL is: app/logout.
I need to show a message - "You are succesfully logged out" in logout page only when logout was triggred by clikcing the logout button.
The message should not be displayed if the user enters this URL directly. Any idea how to implement this?

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView logout(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
            ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
       //some code here to distingish
            model.addObject("msg", "You are succesfully logged out!");
            model.setViewName("login");
        return model;
    }
```

Spring-Security.xml:

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">

```
<http auto-config="true" create-session="ifRequired" use-expressions="true">        
<intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED"/>
    <form-login 
        login-page="/login" 
        default-target-url="/home" 
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error" 
        username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/logout" invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"/>
    <!-- enable csrf protection -->
    <csrf/>
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="mkyong" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is for Spring Security, I think that the simplest way is to use spring security to restrict `/logout` to authenticated users.

Using the namespace it would be :

```
<intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED"/>
```

Using Java configuration, it would be :

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/logout").authenticated()
            ...
}
```

Comment: Facing the error: `Failed to evaluate expression 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED.'`

Comment: @Robby the error of `Failed to evaluate expression 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED` can resolved using this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33443212/3380951

Answer (score 0):

Add  `@RequestParam(value = "foo", required = false) Boolean foo`

Add this additional parameter to logout button, if `foo` exist and is true do your logic

Comment: Thanks. This works. But restricting the logout URL only to authenticated user seems to be better approach. Thanks again. :)

Comment: Yes, it's better solution :)